# How do I take values in a row and add them as new columns in another row?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

How do I take values in a row and add them as new columns in another row (in R preferred)

So I have a large dataset that is formatted like the following:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 12       | 6        | 4
| 2        | 5        | 3
| 6        | 7        | 8
```

with many rows.

I would like the data to be reformatted like:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Column I|
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 12       | 6        |4         |2         | 5        | 3        | 6        | 7        | 8        |
```

Is there a function that would be easily modifiable to do this with a large dataset and multiple rows?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will take an arbitrary data frame and make it a 1-row data frame. There is an implicit matrix conversion along the way, so if you have mixed data types you may need to convert columns at the end.

```
input |> unlist() |> t() |> as.data.frame()
#   Column.A1 Column.A2 Column.A3 Column.B1 Column.B2 Column.B3 Column.C1 Column.C2
# 1        12         2         6         6         5         7         4         3
#   Column.C3
# 1         8
```

This version is all through `list`s so shouldn't do any type conversions:

```
input |>
  lapply(\(x)(do.call(what = cbind.data.frame, args = as.list(x)))) |>
  do.call(what = cbind.data.frame)
#   Column.A.12 Column.A.2 Column.A.6 Column.B.6 Column.B.5 Column.B.7 Column.C.4L
# 1          12          2          6          6          5          7           4
#   Column.C.3L Column.C.8L
# 1           3           8
```

Using this sample data:

```
input = read.table(text = 'Column A | Column B | Column C
 12       | 6        | 4
 2        | 5        | 3
 6        | 7        | 8', header = T, sep = "|")
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform the dataset by adding values from one row as new columns in another row in R, you can use the t() function to transpose the data and then manipulate it accordingly. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ColumnA = c(12, 2, 6),
  ColumnB = c(6, 5, 7),
  ColumnC = c(4, 3, 8)
)

# Transpose the data
transposed <- as.matrix(t(df))

# Combine the rows and convert
new_df <- data.frame(t(matrix(transposed, nrow = 1)))

# Rename the columns
new_names <- c("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD", "ColumnE", "ColumnF", "ColumnG", "ColumnH", "ColumnI")
names(new_df) <- new_names

# Output the transformed data frame
new_df
```